# Finding an independent set S in a digraph with in-neighbors(S) subset of out-neighbors(S)

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-optimization

I am looking for literature that considers following problem

In a digraph G find an independent set D (of minimum, maximum or of size at most k) such that every in-neighbor of D is a also an out-neighbor of D.

I am not aware of the formal keywords used to refer to the problem.

Thanks for your help in advance.